# CreateFont and GetTextMetrics returns weird values

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts

I'm trying to get the `width` and `height` in **pixels** of a fixed pitch font. I'm trying this out right now:

```
SetMapMode(hdc, MM_TEXT);

LOGFONT fontInfo;
HFONT font = CreateFont(6, 0, 0, 0, FW_REGULAR, false, false, false, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, FIXED_PITCH, L"System");
GetObject(font, sizeof(LOGFONT), &fontInfo);
```

Basically, I set the mapping mode to `MM_TEXT`, where I believe 1 unit = 1 pixel, and then I create the font using `CreateFont` with a height in **pixels** of 6, and a width of 0 so it can fill it in automatically.

Now, I need to get the width of the font in **pixels**. I do this using `GetTextMetrics`:

```
SelectObject(hdc, font);
TEXTMETRIC metric;
GetTextMetrics(hdc, &metric);
```

The weird thing is `metric` says the height in pixels (I think) is 15. That doesn't make any sense to me, as I literally specified 6 pixels for `CreateFont`. The width of 8 seems off aswell, as I'm pretty sure this font's `height` is greater than its `width`.

My questions are:

1. What is the proper way to specify the font height in **pixels** for the `CreateFont` function?
2. Does `MM_TEXT` mean 1 unit is 1 pixel?
3. What is the proper way to get the calculated width of a `HFONT`? I specified 0 for the width so it fills it in automatically, now how do I get that value?

Comment: *"What is the proper way to get the calculated width of a `HFONT`?"* - [GetObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getobject).

Comment: Maybe not related to your issues, but it's really important to write error checking code when using Win32. Otherwise you run the risk of trying to understand uninitialized variables.

Answer (score 0):

There is no fixed pitch font with name `System`. Font mapper substitutes another one which it find fits given requirements. If you requested height of `6` and got `15` this probably means that font mapper selected bitmap font which don't offer height bellow 15 pixels.

1
When coordinate mapping mode is set to `MM_TEXT` font mapper treats height argument as measured in pixels, so font height returned by `GetTextMetrics` or `GetTextExtentPoint32` should be very close to argument value (for scalable fonts). Unless specified height is negative. In this case font mapper excludes internal leading from matched font height so usually fonts created this way are slightly larger. When font mapper selects raster (bitmapped) font, there could be huge difference between specified and resultant height, because resultant height selection is limited by available font bitmaps.

2
Yes, in `MM_TEXT` mode 1 logical unit is equal 1 physical unit (pixel).

3
Best method is to measure average width e.g.

```
SIZE    size;
GetTextExtentPoint32( hdc, L"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 52, &size );
int average_char_width = ( size.cx + 26 ) / 52;
```

For fixed pitch font, you can use width returned by `GetTextMetrics` or by measuring width of any reasonable character

```
SIZE    size;
GetTextExtentPoint32( hdc, L"A", 1, &size );
int fixed_char_width = size.cx;
```

Remember that even for fixed pitch font, characters can have different widths (for example CJK - Chinese, Japan, Korean).